# How to fix deployment error for heroku app after re-deploying it. I am running ruby on rails for this particular app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment, heroku-postgres

Recently noticed my Heroku app was flagged as a "Deceptive site", I figured I would try to re-deploy it in order to fix this problem. I did `heroku destroy` + `heroku create` to re-deploy the app on Heroku. However. I am getting a code H10 error, and I do not know what I need to do to fix it after examining the `heroku logs --tail` information. My app is running fine on localhost:3000.

I've tried `heroku restart` and also ran `rake db:migrate`, and those commands all ran without any errors, but the app is still showing an error on the site.

**Edited:
I want to add that I am hitting these errors when I enter *heroku run bundle exec rails db:seed* in the root directory terminal**

Here are the logs I'm getting with heroku run bundle exec rails db:seed --trace:

```
Running bundle exec rails db:seed --trace on ⬢ insta-galaxy... up, run.5183 (Free)
** Invoke db:seed (first_time)
** Execute db:seed
** Invoke db:abort_if_pending_migrations (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:abort_if_pending_migrations
D, [2019-07-15T05:16:53.560424 #4] DEBUG -- :    (1.3ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
D, [2019-07-15T05:16:54.934819 #4] DEBUG -- :    (0.8ms)  BEGIN
D, [2019-07-15T05:16:54.937627 #4] DEBUG -- :   User Create (1.3ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("username", "email", "full_name", "password_digest", "session_token", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "id"  [["username", "Darth Sidious"], ["email", "aletha.gleason@yahoo.com"], ["full_name", "Resistance Bomber"], ["password_digest", "$2a$10$5DECIT74FONj2d61Gt3ifuAvQYqZTZmz0pydq/dabJHDJ8OsIjkYS"], ["session_token", "SI8q4Qghg055ffyxcIQZ-A"], ["created_at", "2019-07-15 05:16:54.935427"], ["updated_at", "2019-07-15 05:16:54.935427"]]
D, [2019-07-15T05:16:54.939614 #4] DEBUG -- :    (1.4ms)  COMMIT
D, [2019-07-15T05:16:54.960686 #4] DEBUG -- :   ActiveStorage::Attachment Load (1.2ms)  SELECT  "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = $1 AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = $2 AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["record_id", 5], ["record_type", "User"], ["name", "image"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
rails aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
(erb):12:in `<main>'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/erb.rb:876:in `eval'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/erb.rb:876:in `result'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activestorage-5.2.2/lib/active_storage/engine.rb:95:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:71:in `instance_eval'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:71:in `block in execute_hook'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:62:in `with_execution_control'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:67:in `execute_hook'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:52:in `block in run_load_hooks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `run_load_hooks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activestorage-5.2.2/app/models/active_storage/blob.rb:235:in `<class:Blob>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activestorage-5.2.2/app/models/active_storage/blob.rb:16:in `<main>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:378:in `block in require_or_load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in `block in load_interlock'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:14:in `block in loading'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:151:in `exclusive'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:13:in `loading'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in `load_interlock'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:356:in `require_or_load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:46:in `block in require_or_load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:16:in `allow_bootsnap_retry'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:45:in `require_or_load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:510:in `load_missing_constant'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:58:in `block in load_missing_constant'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:16:in `allow_bootsnap_retry'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:57:in `load_missing_constant'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:195:in `const_missing'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activestorage-5.2.2/lib/active_storage/attached.rb:20:in `create_blob_from'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activestorage-5.2.2/lib/active_storage/attached/one.rb:24:in `attach'
/app/db/seeds.rb:17:in `block in <main>'
/app/db/seeds.rb:10:in `times'
/app/db/seeds.rb:10:in `<main>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:50:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:50:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:285:in `block in load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:285:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:551:in `load_seed'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:281:in `load_seed'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:194:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:273:in `block in execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:273:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:273:in `execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:214:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/monitor.rb:226:in `mon_synchronize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:194:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:183:in `invoke'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `invoke_task'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block in top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:125:in `run_with_threads'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:23:in `block in perform'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:20:in `perform'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:seed
```

Comment: You will need to show at least the line immediately preceding "all the 'from'-lines from the end of your log".

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to need a bit more information in order to point to what exactly is going wrong in your code. It looks as though your stack trace is actually cut off. You can pull a longer snippet of the logs by running `heroku logs -n=1500`.

Comment: Is there a command to pull the full log? I tried the command you've suggested, however, the logs are still cut off before the "from" word

Comment: From the heroku site: 

“Logplex is designed for collating and routing log messages, not for storage. It retains the most recent 1,500 lines of your consolidated logs, which expire after 1 week. For more production-ready persistence of logs, you can add one of the Heroku platform’s available logging add-ons to your app." 

So not if you have the default logging. You can try running `rails s -e production` locally to see if you can reproduce the error